# tomcat7 Users downloads appearing in the Tomcat home directory

Tags: tomcat

We have an issue that occurs on the test server but not on my dev server.

We have an application that allows the download of either indevidual files or a collection of files in a ZIP.

On both dev & test servers the user can successfully download single or ZIP files

When tomcat is running on the test server & the user selects to download a ZIP the ZIP successfully appears in the userrs download folder via the browser but also appears in the root directory of tomcat.

The servers are using tomcat 7.0.52 & Java7

We have tried different versions of tomcat but to no avail.

Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way those files are going to appear in the root directory of your tomcat server is if your application writes them there. You need to fix the bug in your application that is doing this.

The quickest way to fix this - and as an added bonus will make your server more secure - is to change the file permissions for your Tomcat installation so that the user that the Tomcat process is running under has read but not write permissions for $CATALINA_HOME, $CATALINA_HOME/bin, $CATALINA_HOME/lib and $CATALINA_HOME/conf. You may be able to tighten up the file permissions further depending on circumstances.

Comment: But it can not be the application pre se that has the bug as the issue is server dependent, NOT application dependent. Something I forgot to say is that this is a windows7 installation.